# Question about Android invisible socket connection with Burp

Tags: android, sockets, burp

When i see logcat below i see socket connection to server

```
D/cocos2d-x debug info(22591): Connect m_pTcpMainSock IP:147.139.198.147 Port:26013
D/cocos2d-x debug info(22591): send authen  IP:147.139.198.147 Port:26013
D/NuPlayerDriver( 1415): start(0xb613d040)
I/GenericSource( 1415): start
D/AudioTrack( 1415): use orig AudioTrack! mIsTimed=0 transferType=0 flags=0
D/cocos2d-x debug info(22591): Connect m_pTcpMainSock IP:147.139.197.250 Port:50004
D/cocos2d-x debug info(22591): send authen  IP:147.139.197.250 Port:50004
D/cocos2d-x debug info(22591): Connect m_pTcpAllSock IP:147.139.197.250 Port:50005
D/cocos2d-x debug info(22591): MainSocket pHead->iMsgType=[FFB2]
```

when i intercept through Burp suite the IP noticed before never appeared and cannot logged, any suggestion what's wrong?

Comment: Doesn't Burp only proxy HTTP? Not every TCP connection is HTTP and perhaps that's the case for this connection. Wireshark is the tool to see *everything* happening on the network.

Comment: still no luck with wireshark